# AngularJS, How to submit option value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, select, return-value

Why AngularJS ng-options use label at value instead on value at value?

I use:

```
<select ng-model="gameDay" ng-options="gameDay for gameDay in gameDayOptions">
```

Thats print:

```
<select ng-model="gameDay" ng-options="gameDay for gameDay in gameDayOptions">
<option value="0">Saturday</option>
<option value="1">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

When i submit (get):

```
http://www.domain.com/save.php?gameDay=Saturday
```

I want:

```
http://www.domain.com/save.php?gameDay=0
```

Comment: I am not sure this makes sense to me, your saying if I go to the url, and set gameday to saturday, you want a redirect to the value?

Comment: could you please share the structure of gameDayOptions? Is it an Array of objects or an Array of strings? I guess that it's an Array of strings, right?

Comment: To give an answer what does gameDayOptions look like?

Comment: When i submit form it use option label and i want it use option value. I dont understunt why its use option label?

Comment: gameDayOptions:

["Today | 29.9.", "Tomorrow | 30.9.", "Wednesday | 1.10.", "Thursday | 2.10.", "Friday | 3.10.", "Saturday | 4.10.", "Sunday | 5.10.", "Monday | 6.10.", "Tuesday | 7.10."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that `gameOptons` is an `Array` of strings, therefore what you want to do is this:

```
<select 
       ng-model="gameDay" 
       ng-options="key as gameDay for (key, gameDay) in gameDayOptions">
</select>
```

Because the code that you shared is storing the selected `string` in the `model`, and what you want to store is the index, you can do that by using the following syntax in the `ng-options` directive:

```
ng-options="key as gameDay for (key, gameDay) in gameDayOptions"
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3780eusL/)

Comment: Thats working, thanks. Do you know how i set default selected value. In your case i want Monday is selected by default.

Comment: @Raz000 yep, like this: $scope.gameDay = '0';  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3780eusL/1/ (notice that the key is a string not an int, that's because this syntax can also be used for Objects)

Comment: Now its working like a charm. I try this over week and i almoust surrender. You save my day (week).

Comment: @Raz000 did you try having a look at the official api: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage ?